# Program to search EULA contracts for problems

Tags: text-processing, nlp, legal

I'm looking for a software that could search through the text of a EULA or other contract for suspicious clauses that you might take issue with.

Does such a software exist? and if it does, Where can I get it?

Comment: This requires that the program read the text, understand it, then pass valid legal judgement on it.  Why do you think that is practical with the current state of the art?  [I assume it is not OK if the chosen software simply always says "EULA is ok"?]

Comment: Can you improve your question with pricing information?
Solutions to this range from a regex/NLP solution based ount looking for worrying combinations of words, (which i can imagine, being free and open source) to Legal Expert Systems, valued at thousands to tens of thousands of dollars http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_expert_system

Comment: A *lot* more details would be nice "I heard from someone that there is something that does X" dosen't make an interesting question

Comment: @IraBaxter Even so, judging by the fact that this has an answer, It seems as thought such programs exist anyway

Comment: I'm not surprised something exists. I'm surprised anybody would believe that you should trust it if it doesn't generate a complaint.  If you can't trust it in this case, it isn't an answer.

Comment: A related website is named "EULAscan".  It mostly holds user-submitted reviews of the EULAs of popular software products.  The website seems somewhat broken right now, but you can still browse it [here](http://web.archive.org/web/http://www.eulascan.com/default.aspx?f=b) thanks to the Internet Archive Wayback Machine.  I emailed the website maintainer to tell him about the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are talking about [EULAlyzer](https://www.brightfort.com/eulalyzer.html). It was done by JavaCoolSoftware up to some time ago, now BrightFort LLC. It has some analysis tools that helps you to identify weird clauses about third parties, data collection, advertising, etc.

I have used it and didn't gave me trouble finding stuff in lengthy text nor unexpected behaviors. It comes as freeware with advanced/premium characteristics but the basic covers you for legalese analysis.

Take seriously this note:

> #### Note: This program does not provide legal advice. It can only highlight information that you may want to consider before making your own decision whether to agree to a license agreement or not. You should always consult a lawyer (or other authorized individual) for advice on legal issues.

It only works in Windows up to 7 officially, I haven't tested 8. Doesn't have Linux/Mac counter parts.

Note: it only expects EULA's, if you try another legal document you may not get the desired results.

Comment: How does it do it? Just pattern matching?

Comment: @Undo closed source, so maybe that or maybe word matching... :/